# A non obvious example of a sequence $a(k)\cdot H_{b(k)}$ whose general term is integer many times, where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, harmonic-numbers

For integers $n\geq 1$, $H_n$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number. I am looking examples of arithmetic function $a(k)$ and $b(k)$, whose terms are integers $\geq 1$ and such that the terms of this sequence $$a(k)\cdot H_{b(k)},\tag{1}$$ 
are integers *many* times, or maybe that such quantity is an infinity.

I know examples of proofs (for example from this site Mathematics Stack Exchange, or proposed in [1] as exercise) showing that the $n$th harmonic number isn't an integer when $n>1$, we know it, for $n\geq 1$, the $$H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}$$ is never an integer when $n>1$. And of course the sequence $$n!\cdot H_n$$ is integer for each $n\geq 1$.

> **Question.** I am trying to find sequences of integers $a(k)$ and $b(k)$ (isn't required number theoretic functions), I am saying a non obvious example of an arithmetic function  $a(k)\cdot H_{b(k)}$ satisfying that its general term is integer many times, or maybe even an infinity of such terms are integers. Is it possible? **Many thanks.**

**My no example:** An example with few terms being integers is given as $$c(k):=k\cdot H_{\varphi(k)}$$
when $k\geq 1$, with $\varphi(k)$ denoting the Euler's totient function. Thus here $a(k)=k$ and $b(k)=\varphi(k)$. Then I know that the following terms of our sequence $(2)$ are integers: $1, 2, 3, 6$ and $12$. My example seems that has few terms being integers.

### References:

[1] Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Springer (1976).

[2] *Harmonic Number*, from [MathWorld.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: Maybe I am lacking some terminology, but what is an *arithmetic function*? I know "arithmetic progressions" $an+b$, but this seems not to be what you mean.

Comment: It a sequence, that is the argument of an arithetic function is the *integer* $k$. Many thanks @M.Winter

Comment: Everyone I hope that my question is clear. My english was bad in this post. I am looking a non obvious example of sequence $$c(k):=a(k)\cdot H_{b(k)},$$ where both  $a(k)$ and $b(k)\in\mathbb{Z}$ , being our sequence  $c(k)$ many times an integer, or if it is possible such general term being integer infinitely many times.

Comment: Everyone also is obvious that $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,...,n)\cdot H_n$ is always an integer. I am saying it with the purpose to clarify that I mean it also as an obvious example. Many thanks.

Comment: [Apparently](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02863) $26.41\%$ of the first $10^4$ cases of $H_n$ have a lowest terms denominator equal to $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,...,n)$, so it may be difficult to find "non-obvious" functions

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @Henry , now I am going to read your link. I am going to wait more feedback, and if it is posible what nice examples can we get but I accept you reasoning and help.

Comment: @M.Winter I'm sorry now I read your comment, you've the first paragraph of the Wikipedia [Arithmetic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function) or this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticFunction.html). Also it is required for my exercise that $a(k)$ and $b(k)$ are integers